# How to get the result from onActivityResult method for sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, onactivityresult

In qr scanner reader, after clicking a button it will open the camera and it will scan result. Then it will display result using onactivityresult method.
How to get that result from `onActivityResult` method, and use it in sharedpreferences? Below is my code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        String scanContent = result.getContents();
        customerSno.setText(" " + scanContent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: First thing what is IntentIntegrator? and second you can't get qr code content directly from built in camera

Answer (score 0):

To save the result in `SharedPreference`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("result", scanContent);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve from `SharedPreference`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String result = prefs.getString("result", "No saved result");
```

`context` is your activity context. If this code is in any activity just use `this`

Comment: no need to write anything in onactivityresult method

Comment: You want to save the result you get in `onActivityResult` into a `SharedPreference`, right?

Comment: Then simply call the first code block (of my answer) from the method `onActivityResult`. Or put that code block in a method and call that method.

Comment: Can you send me your emailId

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE){
            IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (result != null) {
                String scanContent = result.getContents();
                customerSno.setText(" " + scanContent);

                SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("result", scanContent);
                editor.commit();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
      }
```